# Trouble when I running CKAN

Tags: ckan

I am new with CKAN. I installed it in my computer. I followed all the steps, I saw that Solr runs ok, but when I would like to run the program, I started PostgreSQL and Jetty, I wrote:

```
. /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate
cd /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan
paster serve /etc/ckan/default/development.ini
```

the aplication returned me `SolrException: HTTP code=404, reason=Not Found`. I am a bit lost.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have configured your solr_url wrong in your development.ini, so when CKAN tries to contact SOLR on it, it gets a 404.

I suggest you check your solr_url:

```
grep solr_url /etc/ckan/default/development.ini
```

which should give you something like `solr_url = http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr` for a single SOLR core or `solr_url = http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/ckan-schema-2.0` for multi-core.

To check SOLR is working, try the admin page with a browser, such as elinks:

```
elinks http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr
```

and check you get the 'Solr Admin' page. (BTW it's the same URL path for both single and multicore setups). If you are running multi-core, check that the last part of the solr_url matches the schema name of the core you want.